# Grails 2.3.6 Missing Repo Issue

Tags: maven, grails, artifactory, buildconfiguration

My Grails (2.3.6) app's `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails {
    project {
        dependency {
            resolution = {
                repositories {
                    inherits true

                    grailsHome()
                    mavenLocal()
                    mavenRepo "http://myartifactory01/myrepo"
                    grailsPlugins()
                    grailsCentral()
                    mavenCentral()
                }
                plugins {
                    compile ":myplugin:0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    server {
        port {
            http = 4384
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `run-app` I get the following error:

```
| Error Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is normally
due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy) or missing
repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. Please verify your
configuration to continue.
```

I have verified that the URL points to a valid (Artifactory) maven repo where the `myplugin` plugin is stored. Is there something wrong with my `BuildConfig`? Is it missing any properties, or is anything misconfigured?

Comment: There is a great post on configuring grails with maven and artifactory here http://wordpress.transentia.com.au/wordpress/2014/04/09/artifactory-and-grails/ . With artifactory you can just use mavenRepo for artifactory with other repos defined in artifactory

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add my mavenRepo before the grailsPlugins since using the Maven dependcy.resolver:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    //mavenRepo "http://myrepo:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot-local"
    mavenRepo "http://myrepo:8081/artifactory/plugins-release-local"

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()

    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add `build ":release:3.0.1"` as a plugin for some reason, me no likes Grails.